# How to Make Python-Twitter Work With Arduino

Tags: python, twitter, arduino

I'm trying to get my Arduino to ring a bell every time the @annoyingbellbot receives the #ringit message. I adapted a lot of this code [this instructable](http://www.instructables.com/id/Tweet-a-Pot-Twitter-Enabled-Coffee-Pot/?ALLSTEPS) but I changed some of it to work with the bell. By the way, I took the twitter API info out so I don't think that is the problem and assume all the spacing is correct. So my problem is that when I tweet at the @annoyingbellbot, nothing happens. It just stays in the loop forever. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
    ##Import Libraries

import twitter
import serial
import time

##authenticate yourself with twitter
api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='',     consumer_secret='',     access_token_key='',     access_token_secret='') 

##set to your serial port
#ser = serial.Serial(port='COM3')
ser = serial.Serial()
ser.baudrate = 9600
ser.port = 3

## check serial port
def checkokay():
        ser.flushInput()
        time.sleep(3)
        line=ser.readline()
        time.sleep(3)

        if line == ' ':
            line=ser.readline()
        print 'here'
## Welcome message
print 'Welcome To Bell Bot!'

def driptwit():
    status = [] 
    x = 0
    drip = []

    status = api.GetUserTimeline('annoyingbellbot') ##grab latest statuses


    checkIt = [s.text for s in status] ##put status in an array
    if len(status) != 0:
            drip = checkIt[0].split() ##split first tweet into words
            ## check for match and write to serial if match
            if drip[0] == '#ringit':
                    print 'Tweet Recieved, Ringing Bell'
                    ser.write('1')
            else:
                    ser.write('0')
                    print 'Awaiting Tweet'
    print "Loop"



while 1:
        driptwit() ## call driptwit function
        time.sleep(15) ## sleep for 15 seconds to avoid rate limiting
```

Comment: What happens when you call the `api.GetUserTimeline` manually?

Comment: I called `print api.GetUserTimeline()`and it gives empty brackets every time

Comment: So the problem is exclusively in the Twitter API. Perhaps wrong parameters are specified. Something like that.

Comment: They python-twitter documentation is hard to get to but I think I had the right parameters considering I copied that part from the instructable. This is very frustrating

Comment: You can test the "send" part of the API first. If you are able to post messages then perhaps you identification parameters are fine and the problem is exclusively in receiving stuff.